# Adding a tool bar to a web page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to add a tool bar (just like the one above the text area where we type our questions in this forum , with bold,italic etc) to a web page.Is there an easier way of doing this?I am using ASP.Net c# and VS2008.
Thankx in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one of the well known ones.

http://ckeditor.com/

Answer (score 2):

There are a bunch. The "most famous" is [tinyMCE](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/), but there is also [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/). If you need an highly customizable solution, you could also try [Wysihat](http://josh.github.com/wysihat/).

Answer (score 2):

there is so many WYSWING editor (open source and commercial) In most of my cases CKEditor was the best option . it is opensource and fully customizable